# How to save each row as a separate file IN A DIFFERENT DIRECTORY in Excel (with the directory name being referenced in one of the column)?

Tags: excel, vba

I have 2 columns in Excel:

```
Folder Name | Content
cat  | Wall of text about how cats are cute but dangerous.
dog  | Wall of text about dogs.
bird | Miscellaneous writings about birds.
```

The parent directory is C:\Users\User\Desktop\Playground

I have 3 folders:

```
C:\Users\User\Desktop\Playground\cat
C:\Users\User\Desktop\Playground\dog
C:\Users\User\Desktop\Playground\bird
```

I want the output of the saved documents to be `parse_me.py`.

**tl;dr: I want this to be generated:**

```
C:\Users\User\Desktop\Playground\cat\parse_me.py
C:\Users\User\Desktop\Playground\dog\parse_me.py
C:\Users\User\Desktop\Playground\bird\parse_me.py
```

---

Currently I've tried using this code https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/excel/how-to-save-each-row-of-a-spreadsheet-as-separate-text-files/m-p/1582516 to generate the .py files but it doesn't exactly do what I want (as it requires an unique number id for each generated file, and I want all the file names to be the same). I also don't know how to modify the code to make it so that it accepts alphabetical letters instead of numerals (so I had not choice but to replace the first column with numbers instead of animal names.

```
Sub SaveAsTextFile()
    Dim strPath As String
    Dim lngID As Long
    Dim strReport As String
    Dim r As Long
    Dim m As Long
    strPath = "C:\Users\User\Desktop\Playground" & Application.PathSeparator
    m = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    For r = 2 To m
        lngID = Range("A" & r).Value
        strReport = Range("B" & r).Value
        Open strPath & lngID & ".py" For Output As #1
        Print #1, lngID; Tab; strReport
        Close #1
    Next r
End Sub
```

The code above generated something like the below, which is no good for me.

```
C:\Users\User\Desktop\Playground\1.py
C:\Users\User\Desktop\Playground\2.py
C:\Users\User\Desktop\Playground\3.py
```

I want this:

```
C:\Users\User\Desktop\Playground\cat\parse_me.py
C:\Users\User\Desktop\Playground\dog\parse_me.py
C:\Users\User\Desktop\Playground\bird\parse_me.py
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```vb
Sub SaveAsTextFile()
    Const SPATH As String = "C:\Users\User\Desktop\Playground\"
    Dim rw As Range, ws As Worksheet
    
    Set ws = ActiveSheet
    For Each rw In ws.Range("A2:B" & ws.Range("A" & ws.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row).Rows
        PutContent SPATH & rw.Cells(1).Value & "\parse.py", rw.Cells(2).Value
    Next rw
End Sub

Sub PutContent(f As String, content As String)
    CreateObject("scripting.filesystemobject"). _
                  opentextfile(f, 2, True).write content
End Sub
```